# EditText not working on specific Android device

Tags: java, android

I have this edit text that's suppose to display the number keypad. It does for all my android emulators and some test devices I have except for the Samsung S3 mini which displays the alpha keyboard. Why is that, and how can I fixed this? My xml is below and I do nothing special in code.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="0"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:digits="0123456789.,"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#fff"/>
```

Comment: does the debugger say anything

Comment: what does not work? The keyboard doesn´t appear if you click on the edittext or is the edittext not visible?

Comment: may be its because of the weight.In that device this weight given may be quite less.Post the full xml

Comment: use `android:inputType="number"`.

Comment: `android:inputType="number"`....yep...but it´s really annoying that manufactures don´t follow the coding rules :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've sometimes had to use the 'phone' input type instead. It depends if that will give all the characters required. Samsung tends to be more customised than one might have guessed.  This is a link https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Type to the android docs.

Answer (score 1):

the `android:digits` rings a bell to me. Sometimes manufacturers customize things. Try leaving that line out and apply the right `android:inputType` for your needs, which in this case appears to be "number"